# Run method class within block

Tags: ruby

How can I use instance variables and method within a block in ruby?

```
class Foo
  @var = "my var"
  def meth()
    "my method"
  end

  Module.something do |variable|
    p @var    #=> Undefined
    p meth()  #=> Undefined
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use `instance_eval`, but you need an instance to call it on.

Comment: that's confusing and will only get you into trouble. I would explicitly pass the var (or self) and access it through its methods. Module.something is badly written if there is an expectation that you will be able things from external closure

Comment: Suppose that Module is an external library. I can't modify Module.something but I need use data from my instance.

Comment: If Module is external, you should pass in the things it needs. The writer of Module cannot know what your class is going to define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the context, but this might help:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @var = "my var"
  end
  def meth()
    "my method"
  end
  def fee
    AModule.something do |variable|
      p @var
      p meth() 
      p variable
    end
  end
end

# test:

module AModule
  def self.something
    yield "bar"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.fee
```